# Assertion failure in -[MPMoviePlayerControllerNew _moviePlayerDidBecomeActiveNotification:]

Tags: ios, exception, crash, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using multiple instances of MPMoviePlayerController, 
Which does not allow playing more than one video at a time
(On different instances of course)

In order not to play two instances at the same time, i stop and dismiss previous player once a new one is playing.

After plying a few videos, it throws an exception which i can't catch because it caused by internal notifications sent between instances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that calling 'stop' method to a player which has loadState == MPMovieLoadStateUnknown, causes bad internal state and throws the exception.

So, the solution was not to allow stopping a player in that state (A player has this state for about a second when it initializes playback).

[Here's a reference to the very helpful mail chain that helped me find it](http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev@lists.apple.com/msg68041.html)